# coefficient of a term in an expansion

Tags: binomial-coefficients

The coefficient of $x^{26}$ in expansion of $(1+x)^{41}(1-x+x^2)^{40}$ is ? Answer is $2082$ now on simplifying i get it as $(1+x^3)^{40}.(1+x)$ now this nowhere gives any coefficient with x to power of $26$ . Wheres my mistake .Thanks!

Comment: So, the coefficient is $0$

Comment: From where do you have the 'answer' $2082$?

Comment: Its given in my book

Comment: I would suggest either the book has stated the wrong answer or you have not shown the correct expression that is stated in the book. Books can and do have mistakes in them.